# java script function disappear after clicking on submit button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, leaflet

When I'm clicking on the submit button the leaflet map flashing and then disappear.
the function that I'm using is GetNewMap() which means when I'm clicking on the button a new lan-long will pass to it.

js:

```
function GetNewMap() {
    
  
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.509865, -0.118092], 12);


 
   L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1

}).addTo(map);
}
```

my view:

```
<form method="get" name="mynewMap" onsubmit="GetNewMap()"> 
 <input type="text" id="Lat" name = "Lat" style="display: none;"> 
<input type="text" id="Long" name = "Long" style="display: none;">

<div class="form-gro row ">
    <div class="col-auto m-2" style="font-size: 16px;">
1- Enter Radius:
    </div>


<input class="col-sm-2 form-control" type="number" id="radius" name="InputRadius" > 

<div class="col-auto m-2" style="font-size: 16px;">
    Meter 
    </div>
 <div class="col-auto offset-3" > 

     <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-info " style="width: 175px;" >Get Tags</button>
   
 </div>
</div>
</form>

<br>
 <div class="col-9" id="map" ></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GetNewMap` method does not prevent the default action. You display a new map, and then the form is submitted to the server, and your new map will disappear.

You need to prevent the form from being submitted:

```html
<form method="get" name="mynewMap" onsubmit="GetNewMap(event)">
```

```js
function GetNewMap(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

[Event.preventDefault() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

As pointed out in the comments, the alternative is to change your `<button type="submit"` to a `<button type="button"`, which would not submit the form. In that case, you would need to handle the button's `click` event rather than the form's `submit` event.

Comment: Your solution is not complete: Your methods make the use of onsubmit senseless. It is better to set the button as type="button" ( this prevent the form to be submitted ) and use onclick="GetNewMap()".
If he want to submit the form anyway, then he can use your method and do a form.submit() at the end. Then using onsubmit make sense.

Comment: @Mephisto If by *"not complete"* you mean *"didn't copy the entire code from the question"*, that was deliberate. Hiding a small change inside a larger code block would make the solution harder to see.

Comment: It was more to point that using onsubmit event without submitting the form, is probably not the best option.

Comment: @Mephisto I added a comment about the `<button type="button"` option to my answer as well.

Comment: @Mephisto "_using onsubmit event without submitting the form_" per se the form _is_ submitted, otherwise the "submit" event would not even fire. You may mean that nothing is sent to the server. In that case, indeed, but it is also a very common Front-end practice. Here the only purpose of the form is to build a map with a Marker, so it seems legit to submit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove `type="submit"` in button and use `onclick` event:

```
<button class="btn btn-info " style="width: 175px;" onclick="GetNewMap()">Get Tags</button>
```

If you want to get the value of `Lat` and `Long` in `GetNewMap()`,try this:

```
 function GetNewMap() {

            var Lat = $("#Lat").val();
            var Long = $("#Long").val();
            var map = L.map('map').setView([51.509865, -0.118092], 12);



            L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                maxZoom: 18,
                id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1

            }).addTo(map);
        }
```